# Deleted users is still shown

Tags: wordpress

I have deleted some users from admin. When I use custom sql to get users with meta values I get the deleted users as well. How can I delete them from admin.

```
$sql ="SELECT *
FROM wp_users u 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um1 ON u.ID = um1.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta  um2 ON u.ID = um2.user_id
WHERE um1.meta_value= '1' AND um1.meta_key = 'show'

GROUP BY u.ID";

$users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Have you checked the wp_users table in your DB to see what's happening?  Looks like the users database entry is not being deleted.

Comment: Yes users really exist in database. In User profile they are not exist.